# How to get corresponding response of corresponding URLConnection, if we use more than one URLConnection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am not sure how should i get corresponding URLConnection response data , if i use more than one URLConnection. Please help me out, i need to use more than one URLConnection?

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every callback you get has the URLConnection as its first parameter, for example

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

So you always know what connection the data belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Eiko, how should i access Request object using Connection, Can i have sample code.

Comment: I don't think you can access the request object from the connection, so you should store this when instantiating the connection.